# How to playback/convert a DV4 file?

Tags: video, playback

I have two .dv4 files, taken from a CCTV and I cannot find a way to use them on either Windows or OS X.

I've tried to open them with several applications, but to no luck!

Does anyone have experience with this kind of files?

Any help will be really much appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to use these files in your workflow?  Transcoding may be more difficult than usual since a proprietary video player may be part of the equation.

Comment: @clint torres Transcoding would be great! the thing is that youtube was able to receive, transcode the file :/

Comment: Check here: http://www.moviecodec.com/file-types/how-to-play-cctv-dv4-file-format-in-pc-85119/

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite standing your last comment @nuc. It sounds like you're saying that since YouTube, a service designed to handle users across the world, can understand the file, your system should be able to?  Quite literally, if any service can use the file, then the people running it have put in the effort to solve all the codec issues - it didn't just run on their system as-is.  If you're really looking to transcode for editing, then which program will you edit with, and which company made the equipment that recorded the files?

Answer (score 3):

Try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [AvTech PlayLite](http://www.moviecodec.com/file-types/how-to-play-cctv-dv4-file-format-in-pc-85119/#msg3038836) (appears to be abandonware). However, from my cursory research, it seems that DV4 videos are supposed to be bundled with proprietary software (check this [Bosch PDF](http://www.vsicctv.com/pdf/DVR4CRemoteSoftwaremanualEnglish.pdf), page 13), so if you're missing that, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary video files are one of the biggest issue for law enforcement investigating on video evidence. If you don't have the native player by the system producer, my company [Amped Software](https://ampedsoftware.com) has developed [DVRConv](https://ampedsoftware.com/dvrconv) a tool to convert most of the formats on the market. We support hundreds of video formats, included the DV4.